# Can't update Ubuntu Repositories

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, updates, repository

So basically the problem is that I can't update my apt cache (Ubuntu 14.04). I recently changed country and ever since I had this sign with the exclamation mark.

I tried to update my cache both with `sudo apt-get update` and tried also changing the repositories server-provider (from settings->software and updates etc).  Note that when I choose "find the closest server", no server can be found.

I tried changing my `resolv.conf`, but it got worse and I had some issues with my wlan too.

Contents of /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
 # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release i386 (20150218.1)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wagungs/kali-linux2/ubuntu raring main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/wagungs/kali-linux2/ubuntu raring main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wagungs/kali-linux/ubuntu raring main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/wagungs/kali-linux/ubuntu raring main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wagungs/kali-linux1/ubuntu raring main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/wagungs/kali-linux1/ubuntu raring main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main
```

Contents of /etc/apt/sources.list.d:

```
diesch-testing-trusty.list
diesch-testing-trusty.list.save
dropbox.list
dropbox.list.save
fkrull-deadsnakes-trusty.list
fkrull-deadsnakes-trusty.list.save
gezakovacs-ppa-trusty.list
gezakovacs-ppa-trusty.list.save
google-chrome.list.save
google-talkplugin.list
google-talkplugin.list.save
kali-tools.list
kali-tools.list~
maxthon-browser.list
maxthon-browser.list.save
midori-ppa-trusty.list
midori-ppa-trusty.list.save
mono-xamarin.list
mono-xamarin.list.save
private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_slimjet_ubuntu.list
private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_slimjet_ubuntu.list.save
spotify.list
spotify.list.save
stebbins-handbrake-releases-trusty.list
stebbins-handbrake-releases-trusty.list.save
strukturag-libde265-trusty.list
strukturag-libde265-trusty.list.save
tualatrix-ppa-trusty.list
tualatrix-ppa-trusty.list.save
ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-make-trusty.list
ubuntu-desktop-ubuntu-make-trusty.list.save
wine-wine-builds-trusty.list
wine-wine-builds-trusty.list.save
```

Pinging google for example:

```
PING google.fritz.box (127.0.53.53) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.039 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.046 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.051 ms
^C
--- google.fritz.box ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.030/0.043/0.051/0.011 ms
```

Results of `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Αγνόησε https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                     
Σφάλμα http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                   

Σφάλμα http://repository.spotify.com testing InRelease                         

Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net raring InRelease                               

Σφάλμα http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              

Σφάλμα http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                 
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://repository.spotify.com testing Release.gpg                       
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                      

Σφάλμα http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                    

Σφάλμα http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                     

Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net raring InRelease                               

Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net raring InRelease                               

Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                               

Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                               

Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                               

Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                               

Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                               

Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                               

Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                               

Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                               

Σφάλμα http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                            
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg                    
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg                  
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                               

Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                               

Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg                             
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg                             
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg                             
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                             
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                             
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                             
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                             
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                             
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg                   
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                             
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                             
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                             
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                             
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                             
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://dl.maxthon.com stable InRelease                                  

Σφάλμα http://download.mono-project.com wheezy InRelease                       

Σφάλμα http://download.mono-project.com wheezy-apache24-compat InRelease       

Σφάλμα http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                               

Σφάλμα http://linux.dropbox.com trusty InRelease                               

Σφάλμα http://dl.maxthon.com stable Release.gpg                                
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://linux.dropbox.com trusty Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://download.mono-project.com wheezy Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
Σφάλμα http://download.mono-project.com wheezy-apache24-compat Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128:
```

The word "Σφάλμα" means error.

Comment: Can you post the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and the list of files and corresponding content inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`? Restore your DNS configuration to what was initially defined: can you `ping google.com`? what does `apt-get update` shows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is your APT proxy, as suggests the message:

```
Unable to connect to 85.73.170.197:3128
```

Port 3128 is known to be squid default port. May be used by some apt-cacher-ng, ... anyway, a cache, most likely. That is no longer reachable.

Either in  `/etc/apt/apt.conf` or some file from `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`, you would have some `Acquire::http::Proxy` that you should drop.

Run `grep -Ri Acquire::http::Proxy /etc/apt`, to confirm/find the file you should edit.